# Random number in range of other number

Tags: python

```
x = 20
data = [None] * x
num = [10]


for i in range(x):
  randomNum = random.randint(-2, 2)
  num[0] = num[0] + randomNum
  num[0] = data[i]
```

So a example would be if i printed data[] would be
[12,10,11,12,13,15,13.....]
This loop should

1. find random num between -2 and 2
2. make += num[0] to randomNum
3. assign data[i] to the number
4. loop for x times

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    num[0] = num[0] + randomNum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I have looked at other questions and other answers and I have found nothing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many Thanks

Comment: You have `num[0] = data[i]` and since `data` is all `None`, you're setting `num[0]` to `None`, so the second time it gets to `num[0] = num[0] + randomNum`, you're saying `num[0] = None + randomNum` and get that error. I'm guessing you mistyped and wanted `data[i] = num[0]` instead.

Comment: In addition to what Grismar said, what exactly is your goal in initializing your list with a bunch of Nones? Python lists aren't fixed length, and you aren't getting any performance savings over just appending data to the list.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks so much I am so stupid I have been staring at this for nearly half a hour 

Comment: You are welcome, we've all been there at some point. I posted an answer below, with some additional observations. Feel free to accept the answer with the checkmark, or close the question if you don't need the answer, so it no longer appears unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `num[0] = data[i]` and since `data` is all `None`, you're setting `num[0]` to `None`, so the second time it gets to `num[0] = num[0] + randomNum`, you're saying `num[0] = None + randomNum` and get that error. I'm guessing you mistyped and wanted `data[i] = num[0]` instead.

You don't really need to initialise variables, unless you're looking to use those values somehow. So, your code can become:

```
import random

# you don't really need x, since it only initialises the range
data = []  # an empty list to assign to
num = 10  # an initial value to start your series off

for i in range(20):
  randomNum = random.randint(-2, 2)
  num = num + randomNum  # num only is one value, so no list needed
  data.append(num)
```

Still, that's all very explicit - this does the same:

```
import random

num = 10
data = [num := num + random.randint(-2, 2) for _ in range(20)]
```

Note that the walrus operator `:=` in there is a fairly recent addition to Python, so don't use that if your script needs to run on old versions of Python.

Here it helps because in addition to working like `=` to assign to a variable, it also returns the value that was assigned, which is what is used here to both modify `num` and get the value into the list comprehension.